# SQL query for insertion multiple data using for loop

Tags: mysql, sql

**My data set**

Tabel Name `Users`

```
unique_id   uid

123487.1    1000
123488.1    
123489.1    
123490.1
```

As shown above this is my existing data and i want to add `uid`, so my data should be displayed as shown below.

```
unique_id   uid

123487.1    1000
123488.1    1001
123489.1    1002
123490.1    1003
```

Comment: The question is: "...using for loop" and it looks that this is not what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need cursors for this.  Just do an `update`:

```
select @u := max(user_id)
from users;

update users
    set user_id = (@u := @u + 1)
    where user_id is null
    order by unique_id;
```

Comment: This is not ok. Where user_id is not null ? It should be is null.

Comment: Also, the `select max(uid) into @u from testTable;` should be the correct code for the `u` variable but I am not sure if it is possible to do it your way, I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uid_update()

BEGIN

 DECLARE Done_c INT;
 DECLARE v_min_id INT;
 declare number_plus int;
 declare v_cur int;

 DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unique_id) rn  
 from testTable
 where uid is null;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Done_c = 1;

 SELECT max(uid) INTO number_plus FROM testTable;

 OPEN curs;

  SET Done_c = 0;
  REPEAT
       FETCH curs INTO v_cur;

       select min(unique_id) into v_min_id 
       from testTable 
       where uid is null;

       update testTable
       set uid = number_plus + v_cur
       where uid is null
       and unique_id = v_min_id ;

       commit;

       UNTIL Done_c END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;

END
```

And then call that procedure like this:

```
call uid_update;
```

The values will then be updated as you asked for.

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6b804e072e5917cc49f165cf9bccff1).

Comment: @SunnySonar . . . A cursor is so not needed for this problem.

Comment: I did not say it is needed, just creating what OP wanted. A loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that uid value is the only a single value in your data set, you can use that simple query:

```
select unique_id, first_value(uid) over(order by unique_id) + row_number() over(order by unique_id) - 1 fv from users;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8102c3ef394d304eefa9d42b5a479ba

Best regards.

Comment: @VBokšić OP didn't mention to update - just to select that data in a specific way.

Comment: The caption of the questiion is: "SQL query for insertion multiple data using for loop". Insertion ! And then you see that the table he begins with(that has null values) is the same as the table he ends with(the one without null values). Ergo, OP wants update. Cheers!

Comment: I see OP marked your question as a best answer, so I guess that's what he wanted. Cheers my friend :)

Comment: OP can always change that :) Welcome to S.O. !